# change style code function VScode time optimisation while coding

Tags: visual-studio-code, coding-style

my goal is change a function to a format where the return value of the function is treated :
For example ; treating a the function `scanf()`

```
Return value of scanf : The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
       either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
       EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
       indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set to
       indicate the error.
```

Thus

```
scanf("%d\n",&i);
```

will be change to

```
#define RVAL(exp) do {if ((exp) == -1) { perror (#exp); exit(1); }} while (0)
...
RVAL(scanf("%d\n",&i));
```

Thus I want this to be done quickly means : 
so what i do is look for occurences of "scanf" and replace it with `"RVAL(scanf"` 
but the problem is i have to add another right parentheses

Can this be done fast ? using a techniques ? or a style ? where each whenever I enter `scanf();` its replaced witch `rval(scanf());`

Comment: if you don't have many `)` in your format string you can use a regex with `(scanf\([^\)]*\));` and replace with `rval(\1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have many ) in your format string you can use a regex with (scanf([^)]*)); and replace with rval(\1);

*see comment